# Why is Judgment Day inevitable?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

In *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*, John Connor asks the T-850 how Judgment Day could possibly take place after the destruction of the things that fulfilled its preconditions, in *Terminator 2: Judgment Day*. The T-850 replies: *"Judgment Day is inevitable."* Why does the T-850 say that?

Comment: Because of stable time loops and John Connor's existence.

Comment: Fixed point in time.

Comment: "fixed point in time" is a concept from Dr Who? As well, the Director's Cut for T2 made it  clear that the future has indeed changed, Judgement Day has been averted, and humanity has been ushered into a new and prosperous age with Sarah looking on as a proud grandmother. Of course, there couldn't be any other Terminator movies otherwise.

Comment: To quote the late, great Sir Terry Pratchett, who as always managed to cut straight to the chase:

“Everything that happens, stays happened."

"What kind of philosophy is that?"

"The only one that works.”

_Thief of Time_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 explanations for this:

1. This is the historical inevitability discussed in Marx's dialectic materialism (you can get more detailed info from Samuel Russell on Politics.SE or History.SE; or may be people on Philosophy.SE).

   High level - human scientific and social development is a well-predictable evolution. Slavery, feudalism, industrial revolution, capitalism, social revolution, socialism/communism (the way the sequence was taught in USSR).

   Like [all progressives](http://blog.blogtalkradio.com/celebrities/james-cameron-george-bush-avatar/), Cameron is more of a Marxist than he either acknowledges or likely even realizes.

   So, the same concept underlies the emergence of Skynet and the Judgement day. Socio/political processes all drive towards more emergent technology that is closer and closer to AI capabilities.

   **Even if there's no T800's arm or a chip to reverse engineer, someone will create the technology from scratch**, earlier or later. If not Cyberdyne Systems, then Google or IBM or some dude in a basement in China.

   And geopolitics dictates that there will be ample WMDs around for Skynet to use.
2. One a more fictional level, there's a fictional trope of "Stable time loops".

   See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel) or [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StableTimeLoop) for details; but the short version is that HAVING a time loop (e.g. having a Terminator in the past) guarantees that somehow he will be sent in the past, no matter what you do. His presence in the present is an invariable constant.

   And since Skynet and Judgement day are required for T800/T850 to be sent back, they will happen.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would point out that dialectic materialism failed to predict the rise of welfare capitalism, and should have produced a large-scale nuclear war. Just because there is all likelihood that a true AI will be invented, and that such an AI will likely be smarter than its creators *and* cause said creators to panic, does not mean that it is inevitable. Cameron - or, more accurately, whoever made the third film, because Cameron only Executive Produced it - made a philosophical and historical error with that comment. The stable time loops possibly evade this.

Comment: It's not very plausible that the notion of an inevitable judgment day was rooted in Cameron's progressivism, since A) progressives usually believe in some improving trend but not in technological determinism and lack of human agency B) the whole plot of T2 showed judgment day as avoidable (Cameron filmed a different ending showing an [alternate future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEaS8X1_gcU) around 30 years after 1997 where judgment day had never happened), and that it possibly only happened in the first place because of Cyberdyne getting future tech, and C) Cameron didn't write T3.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the constants and variables.

There'll always be Judgement day, and there'll always be a protector sent back in time and there'll always be a terminator sent back by SkyNet and John Connor / Sarah Connor are always involved.

Variables though are things like terminator models, the ages of people involved, the date,  the attitude of each character, the people who are killed etc.

Edit: The reason Judgement day has to happen is because if it didn't then there'd be no terminator films, no one to send back in time, no need to protect Sarah Connor and no need to terminate John Connor, because John Connor wouldn't exist.

Comment: Upvote for the Bioshock reference :)

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense when you think about it though.

Comment: This is little more than a re-statement of the T-850's claim that "Judgment Day is inevitable". But *why* is it inevitable?

Comment: I'll give you a chance to edit this, but if you can't come up with an explanation this answer will be deleted.

Comment: Edited it. Its a difficult one to find a reason for to be honest.

Comment: That's an out-of-universe reason. OP is looking for an in-universe answer. Why does the T-850, *in-universe*, claim that Judgment Day is inevitable?

Comment: That's the problem right there. Its never really explained why it has to happen, only that it does.

Answer (score 1):

I think its more of a thing about human nature. Even if we stop skynet and legion, humanity will just keep creating more and more powerful weapons until we make one we can't control. And then judgement day will come.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).